# Need to get a list of all users within a subnet of servers

Tags: windows, scripting, users, remote-access

I am looking to write a batch or vbs script to gather all users 
(local to the server. ie. administrators or a local account(not ad users)) 
on a collection of servers inside my network.

I assume I could do this by subnet. 
Could even put the server names into a csv text file for the script to read from and report back to.
Lots to ask. I would use net user however I run into local access only.

Ideas? Or too many security walls to work?

Update:
I do have access to these servers. It is mostly a security check to make sure that no other admin has changed the template.
Powershell would be fine as well.

I know it can be done. Just been a while...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has too many security walls to work ;) -- Mike I'm guessing you want to find/edit an existing script.  Better to check on Technet's Script Center or elsewhere and see what you can find.  Not really On-topic here.

Comment: So what is your problem here?  Do you have access to all these systems?  If you don't have access to the system, then you can't do anything.  If you do have access, then is the firewall open in a way to permit remote access via powershell/psexec?

Comment: I'd say it's on topic if the OP has access to/is owner of the servers in question

Comment: how is this off-topic? a very common need for a server admin is to manage local and remote users? why doesn't anybody just answer the question around here?

Comment: @RapidWebs Welcome to SF. There is [significant "discussion"](http://meta.serverfault.com/search?q=professional) over what exactly constitutes ["professional"](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity) [capacity]. At times, this hair-splitting makes it difficult to see on which side the line is drawn.

Comment: I understand the argument here, and I suppose that is why stack-exchange is divided into separate websites. i.e. not only for organization purposes, but so that your question reaches the most relevant eyes. however, managing users is a very core aspect in relation to system administration, and "having to many walls to work" doesn't even sound remotely like a issue relating to organization or professionalism. nor does this question wander astray from what constitutes a production system. the only thing I see which is unprofessional is the comments that were written in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using PowerShell

```
computerName = Read-Host 'Enter computer name or press <Enter> for localhost' 

if ($computerName -eq "") {$computerName = "$env:computername"} 
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computerName,computer" 
$computer.psbase.Children | Where-Object { $_.psbase.schemaclassname -eq 'user' } | Format-Table Name, Description -autoSize
```

[source](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/2327.aspx)

or you could use an example from technet, as suggested. [here is one](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-to-retrieve-all-b70a1dba)

Comment: can Powershell read in a txt file with all the $computerNames$ and export the results to a txt or csv? I would do something like that in a bat script... Any possibility for that? By the way thank you for this info.

Comment: check out the Import-csv and Export-csv cmdlet's. for example (read csv to array): $Array = Import-Csv .\test.csv -Delimiter ";"

Comment: some information on Import-csv: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx (Export-csv is mostly the same logic IIRC). if this helps you resolve your issue, please think about accepting my answer. thanks.